# Pandas shows data in a wrong diagram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two functions which both create a diagramm. But when I run those 2 functions, in the second one is the data which should be in the first one. Here are the diagramms:[image]

This diagramm shows the temerature
[image]

And this one should only show the humidity data. Not the humidity and the temperature data.
Here is my source code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime



datum = str(date.today())
date = [datum]

con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")

sql = "SELECT * from data4 WHERE date in (?)"
df3 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con, params=[datum])

def daily_hum():

    df3 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con, params=[datum])
    df3['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df3.date + ' ' + df3.time))
    df3.groupby([df3.datetime]).hum.mean().plot()
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/flask/static/daily_hum.jpg')
  

def daily_temp1():
    
    df4 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con, params=[datum])
    df4['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df4.date + ' ' + df4.time))
    df4.groupby([df4.datetime]).temp.mean().plot()
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/flask/static/daily_temp.jpg')
    
    

daily_temp()
daily_hum()
```

The database/ the DataFrame looks like this:

```
id,hum,temp,zeit,date
721,60,21,11:04:23,2020-06-21
722,64,22,11:04:24,2020-06-21
723,68,22,11:04:27,2020-06-21
724,70,22,11:07:20,2020-06-21
725,63,22,11:08:20,2020-06-21
726,63,22,11:09:21,2020-06-21
727,63,22,11:10:22,2020-06-21
728,63,22,11:11:22,2020-06-21
729,69,22,11:12:24,2020-06-21
730,64,22,11:13:29,2020-06-21
731,70,22,11:14:32,2020-06-21
732,64,22,11:15:33,2020-06-21
733,64,22,11:16:34,2020-06-21
734,64,22,11:17:34,2020-06-21
735,64,22,11:18:35,2020-06-21
736,64,22,11:19:35,2020-06-21
737,64,22,11:20:36,2020-06-21
738,64,22,11:21:37,2020-06-21
739,64,22,11:22:37,2020-06-21
740,64,22,11:23:38,2020-06-21
741,65,22,11:24:38,2020-06-21
742,65,22,11:25:39,2020-06-21
743,65,22,11:26:40,2020-06-21
744,65,22,11:27:40,2020-06-21
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: Could you write `df3` into a CSV file and share it with us so we can help you?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Does it help if you add `plt.close()` or `plt.clf()` after each `plt.savefig()`?

Comment: I updatet it so you can see the dataframe as a csv @Anwarvic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. Matplotlib needs to know, if you want a *new figure* for each plot or not.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime



datum = str(date.today())
date = [datum]

con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")

sql = "SELECT * from data4 WHERE date in (?)"
df3 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con, params=[datum])


df3['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df3.date + ' ' + df3.time))

# new figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Some figure modifying code
fig.suptitle('Titel of Figure')
ax.set_xlabel('X-Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-Label')

df3.groupby([df3.datetime]).hum.mean().plot(ax=ax)
plt.savefig('/home/pi/flask/static/daily_hum.jpg')

# new figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Some figure modifying code
fig.suptitle('Titel of Figure')
ax.set_xlabel('X-Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-Label')

df3.groupby([df3.datetime]).temp.mean().plot(ax=ax)
plt.savefig('/home/pi/flask/static/daily_temp.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was again very helpful! Seems that you are good in that;)@theompm